# How to load an array of external data in QuickChart?

Tags: php, charts, chart.js

I am looking to use QuickChart in my PHP project. I skimmed the [documentation](https://quickchart.io/documentation) completely. But, everything in it has the data being statically loaded as an array. I am trying to load external data, that is generated from somewhere else, into the chart. To understand QuickChart, I tried to load data dynamically in the examples provided in the documentation.

```
<?php
require_once('QuickChart.php');  //the QuickChart.php file is copied in the same folder as this file.

$qc = new QuickChart();
$data = array(50, 60, 70, 180);  //loading data dynamically.
$qc->setConfig("{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Users',
      data: $data  //line with error.
    }]
  }
}");

$a = $qc->getUrl();
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($a));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
?>
```

But, there is an error as follows.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\quickChart\index.php on line 12
```

Following is the example which I modified.

```
<?php
  require_once('../QuickChart.php');

  $qc = new QuickChart();
  $qc->setConfig("{
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Users',
        data: [50, 60, 70, 180]
      }]
    }
  }");

  echo $qc->getUrl();
?>
```

I searched for a while on Internet, but it looks like QuickChart isn't as popular, so there aren't many sources to read.
What is the solution in this case?

Comment: There must be some documentation somewhere

Comment: Does their test example work https://github.com/typpo/quickchart-php

Comment: The example that I have attached at the end is from that folder.
It does work. But, there are no examples for dynamically loading the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a JSON String representaion of an array so for example

```
$jj = json_encode([50, 60, 70, 180]);

$qc->setConfig("{
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Users',
        data: $jj
      }]
    }
  }";
```

Comment: This worked like charm. Absolutely what I needed. Thank you!